# `hg push` : abort: could not lock repository ... Permission denied

Tags: mercurial

I just set up several repositories on my Ubuntu server.  I can pull from them just fine, but when I try:

```
hg push ssh://myserver//hg/repo
```

I get

```
abort: could not lock repository ... Permission denied
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a permissions issue.  The name being used to authenticate must either be the owner of all the files, or be in a group that has write permission to all the files.

Alternatively, you could set the permissions to `777`, but that last `7` is a **really** bad idea, as then anyone who is able to gain any kind of access to the server could play havoc with the repositories.

Comment: A nice solution is to add all users, that would push to remote repository to some common group, e.g. dev_grp. Then set this group for the repository directory and all files inside [sudo] chown -R :dev_grp

Afterwards set permissions to write and read for the group with
[sudo] chmod -R g=rwx .

This way you prevent the need to allow anyone into your repo, while maintaining a degree of cooperation.